# Violin - Scratch Notes as Technique

Tags: technique, violin, harmonics, bow

A friend told me about an "advanced" violin technique involving pressing down with the bow very hard (but not too hard) on a note, producing a kind of scratch note; When done right, however, this technique produces a harmonic-like note LOWER than an open G. I tried it, and sure enough, after a bit of fiddling around with it (hehehe), it worked.

Has anyone ever heard of anything like this, or know what this is called? I have been searching around but have been unable to find anything...

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe that's a wolf tone? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_tone

Comment: Ah more likely it's a subharmonic: http://extendedtechniques.blogspot.com/2012/05/subharmonics.html?m=1

Comment: @ToddWilcox You are correct; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for the sounds you are describing are indeed called **Subharmonics**.  They were discovered by violinist Mari Kimura in the early 1990's and first presented in 1994.

As her website states,

> I first discovered the technique from an age-old bowing exercise, a
>   modified version of "Son Filé", drawing the bow very slowly but
>   applying slightly more pressure.  The exercise was to make the sound
>   steady on the upper E string notes while listening to a scratchy pitch
>   generated one octave below, which I decided by chance to apply for the
>   notes on the G string.  Eventually I managed to eliminate most of the
>   "scratchy" transient noise, thus achieving solid low sounds one octave
>   below on the G string.  The technique has been known among violinists
>   as an exercise or some says even as a quirky 'joke'.  I took this
>   obscure sounds and developed them further, not for the sake of novelty
>   but to use them as a new element for the musical language for the
>   violin.

You can read more about her, her career, and this particular technique [here.](http://www.marikimura.com/subharmonics.html)

Comment: I have no source with it, but a teacher once told us about it with a story dating from before the 1990's.